# TFS Home is gone

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Using TFS I'm used to this view in the "Team Explorer - Home"

[image]

But now, when pressing the "Home" button, nothing appears:

[image]

I haven't found any settings which collapses this view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Cool, you work for Fabrikam!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be connected to a Team Project.  In the first screenshot you're connected to Fabrikam Data Project, but the second screenshot it doesn't look like you have an actual project selected.  If you click the Title ("Home") and go to Select Team Projects you can pick the Team Project + TFS Server you want to connect to.  Then when you come back to Home you should see all the options.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I've should have mentioned that the first image was just a sample from google, but the second was from my actual environment. But it got solved by downloading "Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013" I was as well connected to the correct project.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like 2 different versions of Visual Studio. Make sure you're on the most up-to-date version (2013.4)